# trying to write a telegram bot, but TelegramLongPollingBot() constructor is deprecated

Tags: java, telegram-bot

I'am  novice and I'am trying to write a telegram bot, but TelegramLongPollingBot() constructor is deprecated. So when the app starts, the created bot is null. getBotToken() is also deprecated now, but in TelegramBot API documentation they still mentioning these methods

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;

@Component
public class DemoCountryBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String botName;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String botToken;
    
    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return botName;
    }

    public String getBotTokenAsync() {
        return botToken;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        if(update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()) {
            String messageText = update.getMessage().getText();
            Long chatId = update.getMessage().getChatId();
            String userFirstName = update.getMessage().getChat().getFirstName();

            switch(messageText) {
                case "/start":
                    startCommandReceived(chatId, userFirstName);
                    break;
                default:
                    sendResponseMessage(chatId, "Sorry, command not recognized");
            }
        }
    }

    private void startCommandReceived(long chatId, String userName) {
        System.out.println("Hi, " + userName + "!\nI can give you basic information\nabout any country in the world.\nJust send me a country name in English (like Ukraine)");
    }

    private void sendResponseMessage(long chatId, String message) {
        SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
        sendMessage.setChatId(chatId);
        sendMessage.setText(message);
        try {
            execute(sendMessage);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to write some init method to set the bot.name and bot.token, but they didn´t work. Here is my GeneralBotConfig class code:

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
@Data
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class GeneralBotConfig {

    @Value("${bot.name}")
    @Getter
    private static String botName;

    @Value("${bot.token}")
    @Getter
    private static String botToken;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to `java docs` and `source code` of [TelegramLongPollingBot](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots/blob/master/telegrambots/src/main/java/org/telegram/telegrambots/bots/TelegramLongPollingBot.java)

You should Use the constructor instead it mean that to your current `DemoCountryBot` class add next one `Constructor`:

```
  public DemoCountryBot(String botToken, String botName) {
    super(botToken);
    this.botName = botName;
  }
```

Also according to `java docs` about `getBotToken()`:

> ```
> Deprecated
> Overriding this method is deprecated. Pass to constructor instead
> @Deprecated
> public String getBotToken() {
>     return botToken;
> }
> ```

It mean if you will pass to `constructor` botToken you have not to override the `getBotToken()` method(it will be done after adding that constructor that I gave you above) by the way just delete `override of getBotToken()` from your class.

I mean here about it

```
   public String getBotTokenAsync() {
        return botToken;
    }
```